# Mysql search with ignore special characters

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'products' which has a column `partnumber`.

I want to ignore special characters from record while searching.

Suppose i have following 5 records in partnumber:

```
XP-12345
MV-334-3454
XP1-5555
VX-AP-XP-1000 
VT1232223
```

Now, If i try to search "XP1", then Output should be come like following records

```
XP-12345
XP1-5555
VX-AP-XP-1000
```

How to write mysql query for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality using `concat()` function. As I can review your and Jorden answer comment that you want to search string XP1 with ignore special charecter like `-,_,@` .

So you can use this query

```
SELECT partnumber FROM products 
   WHERE partnumber LIKE concat('%XP','_','1%') 
   OR partnumber LIKE '%XP1%';;
```

Note: Require output you can check on [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e6e2/3) and You can adjust query based on your additional requirement.

Comment: This expression can get extremely complicated if you need to strip out any and each non-alpha character in your search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use REGEXP to allow for containing searches. 
EX:

```
SELECT partnumber 
  FROM partnumber_tbl 
 WHERE name REGEXP '[XP1]\-';
```

This will let it search the database to find anything containing X,P,1.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49fe1/7/0) is a live example.
And [regexp](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm) info for you to look more into. [Official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences), I hate reading them, especially oracles.

.......

Comment: It does not show results property. It should show only those results where XP1 is founded . and if there is any special characters between XP and 1 then it should ignore and show that results too.  Only special characters should be ignore but not required to split each character as separate search term.  'XP" should be combine.

Comment: Sorry, left off \- at the end of it. As long as it's quoted when you escape the character it should work. I updated the link.

Comment: Now it looks better than before. In given example we know that it contains '-' sign, but now suppose i have to ignore @ , _ , and \ character in query, then how to write it. I means it should ignore selected characters from query instead of fixed '-' symbol.

Comment: Is there not REGEXP options to specify a list of custom characters which we want to ignore.  I means can we not modify this REGEXP '[XP1]\-'  ?

Comment: hi, it seems that [XP1]\- dotes not work proper. Just check this
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2431/1        here it also show "AB-XVP1-00000" which should not be there because we should not allow to ignore 'V' characters.

Comment: You can modify a REGEXP however you want. You just need to make sure that you escape any special characters. IE, - needs \- to be located within a string. The way REGEXP works is not for ignoring but for matching. It searches the strings as a value is being entered to see if it matches. If it does, it returns the string otherwise it returns nothing.

Comment: Can you give me example how to ignore special characters only in search results.  For example if i want to ignore - and _ symbol then how to write it.    Lets say there is record "MP-1234","MP_1000" and "M-P1-3456" in database. If i search "MP1" then it should found only "MP-1234" and "MP_1000".  But It should not  show "M-P1-3456"

Comment: Wildcard search should be not between each characters of search terms,. just need to ignore only specified characters. so that proper record may be found.

Answer (score 0):

Define a MySQL function which strips the symbols from a provided string.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION STRIP_SYMBOLS(input VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE output VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE c CHAR(1);
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE i < LENGTH(input) DO
        SET c = SUBSTRING(input, i, 1);
        IF c REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9]' THEN
            SET output = CONCAT(output, c);
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN output;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then select the records from your table where the `partnumber` with the symbols stripped contains `XP1`:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE STRIP_SYMBOLS(partnumber) LIKE '%XP1%';
-- Returns: XP-12345, XP1-5555, VX-AP-XP-1000
```

This might be painfully slow if your table is large. In this case, look into generated columns (if you have MySQL 5.7.6 or higher) or creating a trigger (if an earlier version) to keep a column in your table updated with the `partnumber` with symbols stripped.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT partnumber
FROM products
WHERE REPLACE(partnumber, "_", "")) LIKE '%XP1%');
```